# How can I draw arrows under text with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

[image]
How can I draw this using `tikz`?
Here's what I have so far

```
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\clip(-6.510026062517784,-4.248420559203559) rectangle (13.502591546266133,8.791159555230575);
\draw (-0.9664612545096951,4.467876308733696) node[anchor=north west] {\text{Бүх дэвтрийн тоо}};
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=qqqqff] (-0.8742358078602625,3.810690423162584)-- (2.55240174672489,3.810690423162584);
\draw [->,line width=0.3pt,color=qqqqff] (0.3930131004366807,3.4052576808239583) -- (0.3921359034324833,3.6893270224878867);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=qqqqff] (0.3930131004366807,3.4052576808239583)-- (0.8940799007927491,3.4042724067030448);
\draw [color=qqqqff](0.8290959002853776,3.6807133400543234) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathit{a}$}; \text{ба} \hspace{4cm}  \clip(-6.510026062517784,-4.248420559203559) rectangle (13.502591546266133,8.791159555230575);
\draw (-0.9664612545096951,4.467876308733696) node[anchor=north west] {\text{тараасан дэвтрийн тоо}}; ба
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=qqqqff] (-0.8742358078602625,3.810690423162584)-- (3.55240174672489,3.810690423162584);
\draw [->,line width=0.3pt,color=qqqqff] (0.3930131004366807,3.4052576808239583) -- (0.3921359034324833,3.6893270224878867);
\draw [line width=0.8pt,color=qqqqff] (0.3930131004366807,3.4052576808239583)-- (0.8940799007927491,3.4042724067030448);
\draw [color=qqqqff](0.8290959002853776,3.6807133400543234) node[anchor=north west] {$\mathit{4b}$}; text{гэж тэмдэглэвэл}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to underline text and enter annotated captions into code in Latex. (Above the line in the picture is the text.) Help me.

Comment: You already ask similar question, to which you got answer. It can use it directly on this problem.